# Have SSIS detect the column sizes of a csv file

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to import a csv file into SQL using SSIS and am hitting a fundamental flaw.

SSIS seems to determine that all fields are varchar(50), even though it correctly identifies the comma delimiter.

This is causing issues when I try to send the data to my table in SQL.

Is there a way of making it recognise that a field of length 3 is actually a field of length 3, and not 50?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a Suggest Types function in the Flat File Connection Manager Editor.

Assume you have got a CSV file shown in the first image.

[image: Sample CSV]

Create a new Flat file connection, and browse this file on your computer. The Columns tab shows the sample of the file.

[image: Columns of this CSV in Flat File Connection Manager Editor]

Click Advanced tab. There you can see all columns have `DT_STR` type with the length of 50. What you can see is the Suggest Types... button. Click this.

[image: Advanced settings of CSV]

Set parameters as you like. Defaults are all right in my case. Click OK.

[image: Suggest Types...]

Now the first column has the type of `DT_STR` with the length of 1. (The other two columns have got new types as well. The Number column got `DT_I1` (because we choosed the smallest appropriate integer type option), and the Date column got `DT_DATE`.

[image: Types changed]