# Identify highest possible datatype

Tags: sql-server, types

I have imported data from CSV into a SQL-Server Database Table. Now everything is a String and I am looking for a way to get most specific datatype for all columns and create a table with the data and this datatype. I found way to identify the existing datatype but that is not what I want.

For example let us say there is a `12`. A `12` can be a string or an int. Int is more specific.

Comment: I mean the most specific datatype. Let us say there is a 12. A 12 can be a string or an int. Int is more specific. This is what I mean with highest possible datatype.

Comment: How do you intent to import the CSV file ?

Comment: I import it via bulk insert.

Comment: what i can think off is to `bulk insert` into a all string staging table, then you need to parse each column and every row. see if values of all rows are numeric and decide what data type to use. This is not going to be an easy task. You need to consider integer, decimal, string  or may be date / datetime

Comment: Do you thing it is going to be a problem if not every entry has a value set. Like Column 1 values (with 4 rows) has "1", "5", "", "2" ?

Comment: Not really a problem. You need to define the rules and decide on what data type to use  for each condition. And for example this case, you need to choose string or integer

Answer (score 1):

If the import is done using SSIS, it has such built-in functionality:

[Have SSIS detect the column sizes of a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373039/have-ssis-detect-the-column-sizes-of-a-csv-file):

[image]

and then, by clicking on Suggest Type:

[image]